# links pre-filled messages on social sites

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking

I've written a simple tool that lets users keep track of some stuff (to make it simple, lets say they're entering their weight every day).  Throughout the site, I want to add links to social sites, where user could share that info.  Example: after user successfully adds a new record, I'd like to show him links that when clicked would redirect him to twitter, facebook and similar sites with a pre-filled message: "my weight today is XX kg".  On the graph page, I'd show links that would contain a different string ("see my daily weight graph").

I tried at http://www.addthis.com, but it only offers pre-filled messages for twitter.

I don't really want to spend X days reading APIs for every major social website out there... can you guys suggest a solution?  Either a resource with specs of links, some 3-rd party app (I'd look at the code), or some web service like addthis.com...

Answer (score 4):

For Twitter:
http://twitter.com/home?status=My+weight+today+is+XX+kg 
Also have a look at http://tweetmeme.com/

For Facebook:
http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?&message=My+weight+today+is+XX+kg

Comment: Facebook no longer allows that method.